# CloudWatch Events rule Limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-lambda

what is the maximum number of rules for cloud watch I can create on my AWS account. I might have a lot of different rules that will invoke lambda function on schedule. Is it unlimited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to AWS cloud watch team  I found out that the rule limit can be increased as per your need.

Answer (score 8):

The basic limits are documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudwatch_limits.html - currently 50 rules per account.

If you need more, reach out through your AWS contact and these can be expanded.

Comment: thanks @tim. I just found it on their documentation as well. I still wonder can we expanded it to 10k or so. what would be the implications of expanding this, will it affect the performance, we are kinda using for mission critical apps and the performance really matter. I have to ask them all these and will update their answer here.

Comment: Performance should not be affected by the number of rules.  It’s just that this is a new service and we’re easing its way into the world.  Go ahead and ask for the increase.

Comment: When in doubt ask for the limit to be increased.  If they approve it then you are good, if it is denied they should provide you with some additional information.

Comment: AWS is now recommending to use Amazon Event Bridge which (currently) has a quota of [500 rules per event bus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-quota.html). The quota can be increased on request. For reference the original [CloudWatch Events quota doc](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-cloudwatch-events-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/cloudwatch_limits_cwe.md).

Answer (score 5):

This is no longer 50 and has been increased to `100 per region per account`.

As per this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/cloudwatch_limits_cwe.html

And as mentioned by johnny: this can be increased further on request (if amazon approves the request).

Comment: and can further be increased on request.

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct, 100 rules per account by default.

Comment: it is  true your response.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023**

It looks like AWS has actually increased the limit to `300 per account per region` for some regions.

```
af-south-1: 100

eu-south-1: 100

Each of the other supported Regions: 300
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're willing to use a non-AWS service, then you might check out [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/). Azure offers a great [job scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) that doesn't pose any limits. You could use this service to invoke your lambda functions.